# How to save HLS stream to local disk in source code by ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, record, http-live-streaming

The HSL stream is divided into multiple ts files, now I want to save these files and the m3u8 file to local disk in source code by calling ffmpeg APIs.

Does ffmpeg support this function? If so how to implement the function? Otherwise, can anyone give me some suggestions about how to achieve this goal?

Comment: You haven't said anything about the platform/code/language you plan to use  so this can't begin to be answered as the question is now stated.

Comment: @rainabba, I suspect if you know what is ffmpeg.

Comment: And, do not comment the question you ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH, whats a joke.

Answer (score 5):

Try this from [videohelp](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/348274-Record-HLS-streams) please.

```
ffmpeg -i http://hls.twit.tv:1935/flosoft/smil:twitStream.smil/playlist.m3u8 -t 30 -c copy output1.mkv
```

Comment: I want to do it in source code, not by ffmpeg command line. but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>

char url[1000][100];
char channelname[1000][100];
char playlist[1000][50];
int totalURL;


size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void downloadFile(char *link, char *outfilename) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename, "wb");
        if (!fp) {
            printf("File \"%s\" Can't open. Error: %d[%s]\n", outfilename, errno, strerror(errno));
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            return;
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

void getNewLink(int myIndex, FILE *fp) {
    char line[1000], link[1000], outfilename[256];
    int i, j = 0, len;
    FILE *fp1;
    int flag = 0;
    memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (fgets(line, 1000, fp) == 0) {
            if (!feof(fp)) {
                printf("Error in File reading.\n");
                fclose(fp);
            }
            return;
        }
        len = strlen(line);
        if (line[len - 1] == '\n') {
            line[len - 1] = '\0';
            len--;
        }

        for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\t') {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (line[i] == '\0') {
            continue;
        }

        if (!strncmp(line, "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:", 15)) {
            flag = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if(flag == 1){
            flag = 0;
            memset(link, 0, sizeof(link));
            strcpy(link, url[myIndex]);
            strcat(link, channelname[myIndex]);
            strcat(link, "/");
            strcat(link, line);
            sprintf(outfilename, "chunk.m3u8");
            downloadFile(link, outfilename);
            fp1 = fopen(outfilename, "r");
            if (!fp1) {
                printf("File \"%s\" Can't open. Error: %d[%s]\n", outfilename, errno, strerror(errno));
                continue;
            }
            getNewLink(myIndex, fp1);
            fclose(fp1);
            continue;
        }

        if (!strncmp(line, "#EXTINF:", 8)) {
            flag = 2;
            continue;
        }

        if (flag == 2) {
            j++;
            memset(link, 0, sizeof(link));
            strcpy(link, url[myIndex]);
            strcat(link, channelname[myIndex]);
            strcat(link, "/");
            strcat(link, line);
            memset(outfilename, 0, sizeof(outfilename));
            sprintf(outfilename, "%s\\chunk%d.ts", channelname[i], j);

            downloadFile(link, outfilename);
            flag = 0;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

void readFile(char *filename) {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[1000];
    int i, j, len;
    memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("File \"%s\" Can't open. Error: %d[%s]\n", filename, errno, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (fgets(line, 1000, fp) == 0) {
            if (!feof(fp)) {
                printf("Error in File reading.\n");
                fclose(fp);
            }
            return;
        }
        len = strlen(line);
        if (line[len - 1] == '\n') {
            line[len - 1] = '\0';
            len--;
        }

        for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\t') {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (line[i] == '\0') {
            continue;
        }

        if (strncmp(line, "http", 4)) {
            printf("Ignoring comment line.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!strncmp(line, "http", 4)) {
            for (j = 0; i < 100 && j < 100 && line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {
                url[totalURL][j] = line[i];
            }
            url[totalURL][j] = '\0';
            printf("url: %s\t", url[totalURL]);
        }

        for (j = 0, ++i; j < 100 && line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {
            channelname[totalURL][j] = line[i];
        }
        channelname[totalURL][j] = '\0';
        printf("%s\t", channelname[totalURL]);

        for (j = 0, ++i; j < 50 && line[i] != '\t' && line[i] != '\0'; i++, j++) {
            playlist[totalURL][j] = line[i];
        }
        playlist[totalURL][j] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", playlist[totalURL]);

        totalURL++;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char link[200];
    int i;
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX];

    //analyzer file format should be like this: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/ bipbop  bipbopall.m3u8"
    //    http_link\tsub_path(OR some folder)\t*.m3u8
    readFile("analyzer.txt");


    printf("\n\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < totalURL; i++) {
        memset(link, 0, sizeof(link));
        strcpy(link, url[i]);
        strcat(link, channelname[i]);
        strcat(link, "/");
        strcat(link, playlist[i]);

        printf("URL: %s\n", link);

        mkdir(channelname[i]);
        memset(outfilename, 0, sizeof(outfilename));
        sprintf(outfilename, "%s\\%s", channelname[i], playlist[i]);
        printf("outputfile: %s\n", outfilename);

        downloadFile(link, outfilename);
        fp = fopen(outfilename, "r");
        if (!fp) {
            printf("File \"%s\" Can't open. Error: %d[%s]\n", outfilename, errno, strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
        getNewLink(i, fp);
        fclose(fp);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have not been worked with ffmpeg two years :)

Comment: I know that I gave very late response but I hope it will help someone :)